# NetworkOnMainThreadException using RX2 in Android

Tags: java, android, system.reactive

Here studying RX implementations.

My question:
It's possible to run this code here without any asynctask/runnable?
As I understand RX makes new thread for himself. Can it made runnable?
This code returns NetworkOnMainThreadException

class TestInternet

```
public class TestInternet implements SOService.TestInternet {
    //TIMEOUT EN MILISEGUNDOS
    private final int MILISECONDS = 3000;

    @Override
    //returns the observable with connection/no connection
    public Observable <Boolean> getObservableConnection(String filter) {


            Observable<Boolean> networkAvalaible;

            try {
                    URL myUrl = new URL("http://flickr.com");
                    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(MILISECONDS);
                    connection.connect();

                    networkAvalaible = Observable.just(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    //I'm catching NetworkInMainThreadException here
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    networkAvalaible = Observable.just(false);
                    Log.d("error en testinternet",e.toString());
            }


            return networkAvalaible.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    }
```

from presenter.java

```
testInternet.getObservableConnection(filtro).subscribeWith(getConnectionObserver());




//comprueba conexión
public DisposableObserver<Boolean> getConnectionObserver() {
    return new DisposableObserver<Boolean>() {

        @Override                //envia los datos al recyclerview
        public void onNext(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) {
            Log.d("rx","CONNECTION HAY NEXT");
            //envia los datos al recyclerview
            if (!aBoolean){
                Log.d("connnexcion", aBoolean.toString());
                mainView.showError(mainView.getContext().getText(R.string.no_connected).toString());
            }else if (aBoolean){
                Log.d("connnexcion", "on next correcto");
                mainView.hideError();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you have permissions?

Comment: INTERNET & ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: Do you implement the Observable?

Comment: the answer of Марат Зангиев explains perfectly. Is needed to call from inside the observer (not just return a observer true or false)

Comment: Nice, It is important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this exception because you make network call on Android MainThread in this line:
`URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();`
Rx handle multithreading by `Schedulers` (`subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` in your code). But you make your network call outside an `Observable`
Wrap your call inside an `Observable` and it will work

**Your edited code**

```
public class TestInternet implements SOService.TestInternet {
    //TIMEOUT EN MILISEGUNDOS
    private final int MILISECONDS = 3000;

    @Override
    //returns the observable with connection/no connection
    public Observable <Boolean> getObservableConnection(String filter) {  
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Boolean> emitter) throws Exception {
                try {
                    URL myUrl = new URL("http://flickr.com");
                    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(MILISECONDS);
                    connection.connect();

                    emitter.onNext(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //I'm catching NetworkInMainThreadException here
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    emitter.onNext(false);
                    Log.d("error en testinternet", e.toString());
                }
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()); 

    }
```

Comment: you are a boss!